# MFC: draw in a control

Tags: mfc

Looking for some code/project examples on how to draw a pulse waveform with certain width/frequency in a MFC control. Which control would be the best to use for this purpose?. I am very new to this. Have already done some online search and definitely can use some expert ideas. I am lost.

Comment: A picture control might seem like the natural choice, but those get implemented as a `CStatic` which resist being updated dynamically. I'd probably go for a custom class derived from `CWnd`.

Answer (score 1):

The MFC `CStatic` class represents a picture control. You can derive a class from `CStatic` and paint whatever you like in its `OnPaint` member function.  For examples search codeproject.com and codeguru.com for "CStatic", like this one:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/controls/chartingandanaloguecontrols/article.php/c5219/Simple-Graph-Control.htm